# flexigrid WITHIN a fancy box modal window

Tags: jquery, fancybox, flexigrid

After a lot of headache I got it working, only after i wrapped it in a hidden div and used fancy box to display an inline content modal... the buttons and actions within the grid does not work. I have searched it all day and night.

How can I get flexigrid pagination, refresh and other buttons work within a fancybox inline content modal popup?

HTML:

```
<div id="gameOnline" style="display:none"><div class="contenWraps"><table id="playerGrid"></table></div></div>
```

Every thing works just fine without a modal, but once in fancy box the interaction of the grid breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is to forget it and use iFrame modal instead on inline content, problem solved. Remember `'type': iframe` and `'href':` to what ever url path you want.